# Grep string which contains square brackets

Tags: grep, regular-expression

This is  the data

```
10:43:19.538281|TraceDetail    |UPBSStandardGenericBillPaymentComponent.PostBillPaymentTransaction|Total Time    19/06/2019 10:43:19.538281|TraceDetail    |UPBSStandardGenericBillInquiryComponent.GetBillInquiry()|Total Time                    |2361748             | Consumer Number [0312122221212             ] , UCID [KLOJ0001] ,  Sending Time [10:43:17.8425459] Receive Time [10:43:18.4941158] Total Time [0:0:651] STAN is [345949]
```

I want output

```
[0312122221212             ]
[KLOJ0001]
[10:43:17.8425459]
[10:43:18.4941158]
[0:0:651]
[345949]
```

I have tried so many commands but didn't able to achieve the result with following command:

```
grep -oP 'Consumer Number \K.{26}|UCID \K.{10} |Sending Time \K.{09}|Receive Time \K.{09}|Total Time \\[ \K.{8}|STAN is \K.{8}' /root/Documents/a.txt
```

I got output without total time:

```
[0312122221212             ]
[KLOJ0001]
[10:43:17.8425459]
[10:43:18.4941158]
[345949]
```

And when I try this command:

```
grep -oP 'Consumer Number \K.{26}|UCID \K.{10} |Sending Time \K.{09}|Receive Time \K.{09}|Total Time \K.{8}|STAN is \K.{8}' /root/Documents/a.txt
```

I got invalid values in output:

```
19/06/
[0312122221212             ]
[KLOJ0001]
[10:43:17.8425459]
[10:43:18.4941158]
[0:0:651]
[345949]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use simply this:

```
grep -oP '\[.*?\]' /root/Documents/a.txt
```

`\[`   matches a literal `[`

`.*?`  matches any number of chars, 
in a non-greddy (lazy) way.

> [Laziness Instead of Greediness](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

`\]` matches a literal `]`

---

Now, I'll try to explain what went wrong with your regexes.

this one:

> `grep -oP 'Consumer Number \K.{26}|UCID \K.{10} |Sending Time \K.{09}|Receive Time \K.{09}|Total Time \\[ \K.{8}|STAN is \K.{8}' /root/Documents/a.txt`

is broken: `grep: missing terminating ] for character class`
you probably paste it badly here... check that out.

And this one:

> `grep -oP 'Consumer Number \K.{26}|UCID \K.{10} |Sending Time \K.{09}|Receive Time \K.{09}|Total Time \K.{8}|STAN is \K.{8}' /root/Documents/a.txt`

Could be fixed:

```bsh
grep -oP 'Consumer Number \K.{29}|UCID \K.{10} |Sending Time \K.{09}|Receive Time \K.{09}|Total Time \K[^/ ]{9}|STAN is \K.{8}' /root/Documents/a.txt
```

but bare in mind that this in not the best way to do it... the problem with your original regex was that you were too permissive; so, you were matching things you don't intended; if you know that some match should only contain, say, `[`,`numbers`, `space`, and `]`, don't use `.{29}`... this is SO permissive with no point: be more precise, for example, like this: `[][0-9 ]{29}`

Comment: Thank you for your response but it'll not help because sometimes there might be some more values occur in square brackets which i don't want. so it is necessary to grep only data which comes after some specific string.

Comment: No problem; creck my updated answer.